# Convert day date to Unix Timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can i convert day date (for example, **22** which stands for 1/22/2017) to Unix Timestamp (after conversion result needs to be **1485079018**) in javascript.

I tried code below without luck.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();
var g = Math.round(new Date().getDate()/1000);
```

Comment: Do you need to worry about leap seconds or not?

Comment: I don't need to worry about that

Comment: The first two lines of your code seem to be irrelevant. The third will get the current date (i.e. day number in the month) which is currently 22 and divide it by 1000. You can use  `new Date().getTime()/1000` or just `new Date()/1000` to get a UNIX time value in seconds for the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to Unix Timestamp (after conversion result needs to be 1485079018

The Unix timestamp 1485079018 is Jan 22 2017 at 09:56:58 UTC. Where are you getting that 09:56:58 from?

In terms of the problem, if I assume you actually want midnight UTC rather than 09:56:58, see comments:

```js
var day = 22;
// Create the date (in UTC)
var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 0, day));
// Or not UTC, but then we get really far afield of Unix timestamps:
//var dt = new Date(2017, 0, day);
var ts = Math.round(dt / 1000);
console.log(ts);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps alot, one more question, if i would like to replace 2017, to be dynamic, for next year, how could i set it?

Comment: @ofer_e: Just...use 2018 instead of 2017. If you're wondering how to get the current year as of right now, in UTC it's `new Date().getUTCFullYear()` and in local time it's `new Date().getFullYear()`.